# RSpec and expecting PG:RaiseException

Tags: ruby, postgresql, rspec

I am trying to write the test. The database should raise the exception and I want to check, that exception is raised.

```
expect { save_to_db(@params)}.to raise_exception(PG::Exception)
```

But

```
RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError: expected {:PG=>Exception} but nothing was raised
```

Even when I get

```
  ERROR - 27/Feb/2020 10:52:19 PG::RaiseException: ERROR: Message ...
```

Any tips, please? :)

Edit:

Fix typo, now result is

```
RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError: expected PG::RaiseException but nothing was raised
```

I tried different combinations, using `raise_error` and `PG::Error` but still unable to catch and handle.

This is first try

```
expect { save_to_db(@params)}.to raise_exception(PG::RaiseException)
```

and returns:

```
RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError: expected PG::Error but nothing was raised
```

If I try to override our method `save_to_db()` and paste the post url:

```
expect { page.driver.post("send/?records=#{records_id}")}.to raise_exception(PG::RaiseException)
```

I get the same error

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in `raise_exception(PG:Exception)` - it must be `raise_exception(PG::Exception)` (note the double colon instead of single one).

As the result, it is parsed as a hash value `{:PG => Exception}` (`:PG` is a valid symbol, `Exception` constant is defined, so no complaints from the Ruby parser) that is passed to a `raise_exception` matcher. So, in fact you expect *any* error with the particular message (equal to the hash you provided) - and for sure actual `PG::Exception`'s error message is different...

Try fixing this typo first - it might solve the problem.

Comment: Sorry, this typo was just here, situation remains the same, I will edit my post

Comment: It seems this is not the only difference with the actual code :) The error message says `expected PG::RaiseException` but in the snippet you posted you expect `PG::Exception` to be raised... So what is the actual test code that you're trying to execute? :)

Comment: Sorry :) I am trying combinations to figure it out, I changed raise_exception to raise_error, bad copy-paste. I don't care if there will be raise_exception or error if it works :)

Comment: AFAIR `raise_exception` and `raise_error` are in fact the same matcher, so they are absolutely interchangeable. Did you try debugging? :) What _actual_ error do you receive when you call `save_to_db(@params)` from the console in the same context?

Comment: I think so. Yes I got the same exception like using url, it is from RAISE EXCEPTION from our Psql functions. I can see the exception on the terminal, but raise_* is not catching it.

Comment: So if I run all the tests it fails but everything is okay for `expected PG::RaiseException but nothing was raised (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)`